# Get CSV values for words in list

Tags: python, csv, text, pandas

I try to figure out how I can compare tokens in a text file with data in an excel file.
I turned the text to a list of tuples, and I can read my data from csv file, which looks like this (but a lot bigger):

```
      name   score1   score2   score3
      arm    1        2        3
      beard  4        5        6
      chin   7        8        9
```

I turned my text into a list of tuples, looking like this:

```
[(0, 'My'), (1, 'arm'), (2, 'has'), (3, 'no'), (4, 'chin'), (5, '.')]
```

What I want to do, is iterating over the names in my datafile, return the respective scores and create a new list out of it:

```
[(0, 'My'), (1, 'arm', 1, 2, 3), (2, 'has'), (3, 'no'), (4, 'chin', 7, 8, 9), (5, '.')]
```

I can read the scores in a certain row

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv')    
names = data[:1][['score1', 'score2', 'score3']]
```

I also can check for a specific word in those names:

```
names.str.contains("arm")
```

My trouble is now, that I neither know how to retrieve the scores for a non-specific name (not just `data[:1]`) but for an iterable variable. Nor do I know how to check my "names" for *any* string in my text.

**EDIT** changed the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use case is simple enough that I'd suggest not to use external libraries (except pretty printing, of course...).

The code is commented, and also the output it produces is commented...

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

# you don't need to store the ordering in a list,
# because lists are ordered by their nature 
text = ['My', 'arm', 'has', 'no', 'chin', '.']
print 'Text to annotate'
pp(text)

# slurp the data, throw away the header, split on whitespace
data = [row.split() for row in open('datafile.csv').readlines()[1:]]
print '\nData as a list of rows'
pp(data)

# turn into a dictionary with lists of ints
data = {row[1]:[int(elt) for elt in row[2:]] for row in data}
print '\nData as a dictionary of lists of scores'
pp(data)

annotated_text = [tuple([word]+data[word]) if word in data else (word,)
                  for word in text]
print '\nAnnotated text'
pp(annotated_text)
print '\nNB: the order of the words in the text is preserved in the annotated text.'
```

Saving the above in a file and executing has given me the following oputput

```
Text to annotate
['My', 'arm', 'has', 'no', 'chin', '.']

Data as a list of rows
[['0', 'arm', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['1', 'beard', '4', '5', '6'],
 ['2', 'chin', '7', '8', '9']]

Data as a dictionary of lists of scores
{'arm': [1, 2, 3], 'beard': [4, 5, 6], 'chin': [7, 8, 9]}

Annotated text
[('My',), ('arm', 1, 2, 3), ('has',), ('no',), ('chin', 7, 8, 9), ('.',)]

NB: the order of the words in the text is preserved in the annotated text.
```

#### Edit: an interactive session that displays the intended output

I stripped comments and most printouts.

```
% cat test1.py
text = ['My', 'arm', 'has', 'no', 'chin', '.']
data = [row.split() for row in open('datafile.csv').readlines()[1:]]
data = {row[0]:[int(elt) for elt in row[1:]] for row in data}
annotated_text = [tuple([w]+data[w]) if w in data else (w,) for w in text]
print annotated_text
% cat datafile.csv 
       name   score1   score2   score3
       arm    1        2        3
       beard  4        5        6
       chin   7        8        9
% python test1.py 
[('My',), ('arm', 1, 2, 3), ('has',), ('no',), ('chin', 7, 8, 9), ('.',)]
%
```

Comment: @PeterClotz Not the answer you were looking for?

Comment: That's pretty awesome. But I don't get quite the same results: The data dictionary gives me empty scores    {'arm,1.0,2.0,3.0': [], 'beard,4.0,5.0,6.0': [], 'chin,7.0,8.0,9.0': []}   The annotated_text seems to be a set of tuples with only the words in it, like this: [('My',), ('arm',), ('has',), ('no',), ('chin',), ('.',)]    I try to figure out why this is, but I don't get it

Comment: I fear there is a typo, in one line it is `annotated_test` and in the other one it is `annotated_text`. Choose one and edit the other...  (I edited my answer) If you still have problems, is it possible that our data files differ? I just checked (again) and I see the correct output!

Comment: I did a literal copy of your data file, as posted in your Q.  Your real data file is maybe different?

Comment: I see: I noticed the test/text, but gave wrong data: what I listed was the file read with pandas, so there is no column with 0 1 2! I edited my original post. What a mistake.

Comment: Then change the indices when building the dictionary 'data = {row[0]:[int(elt) for elt in row[1:]] for row in data}`.

Comment: Hmm...I did that before and it gave me the results I posted above.  So because the lists in the dictionary are empty there is no annotation to the text?

Comment: Well, thanks a lot! I was able to solve the issue. That was really helpful!